# remove event listener implementation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a removeEventListener(off) method. I have placed the code below. `off` method is removing the event which is added by `on`.

However, when `once` is used,  `off` method is not removing the event. How can I fix this?

```js
class Emitter {

    constructor() {
        this.events = {};
    }

    on(eventName, callBack) {

        if (!this.events[eventName]) {
            this.events[eventName] = [];
        }

        this.events[eventName].push(callBack);

        return this.events[eventName].length;
    }

    off(eventName, callBack) {

        // First get the correct event
        let list = this.events[eventName];
        
        // Check that the event exists and it has the callback registered
        if (list) {
            //  if no callback function provided, then all functions are unsubscribed
            //  event has no callbacks left, delete the event
            if (!callBack) {
                delete this.events[eventName];
            } else {
                // if it is registered then unregister it!
                while(list.indexOf(callBack) !== -1) {
                    // If the callback is in the array then remove it
                    let index = list.indexOf(callBack);
                    list.splice(index, 1);
                }

                // if the event has no callbacks left, delete the event
                if (list.length === 0) {
                    delete this.events[eventName];
                }
            }
        }

        return (this.events[eventName] || []).length;
    }

    once(event, fn) {
        //If the event name is not a string data type throw error
        if (typeof event !== 'string') throw Error();

        // If the callback is not a function data type throw error
        if (typeof fn !== 'function') throw Error();

        function g () {
            this.off(event, g);
            fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        g.fn = fn;

        this.on(event, g);
        return this.events[event].length;
    };
}

let e = new Emitter();
console.log(e.events);
function test(){};
e.on('test', test);
console.log(e.events);
e.off('test', test);
console.log(e.events);

console.log('==========');
console.log(e.events);
function test(){};
e.once('test', test);
console.log(e.events);
e.off('test', test);
console.log(e.events);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `e.off('test', test);` doesn't remove the handler is because `test` is not the handler you are adding to `this.events[eventName]` with `.once`. You are creating a new function `g`, and *that* is the one that is stored in `this.events[eventName]`. `.off` however only looks whether the function you pass as argument is contained in the array, which will not be the case.

> How can I fix this?

There are various ways to fix this. Often subscription methods actually return a *token* or some other value that can be used to unsubscribe. The advantage of this is that the caller doesn't have to keep a reference to the handler around. Example:

```
once(event, fn) {
    //If the event name is not a string data type throw error
    if (typeof event !== 'string') throw Error();

    // If the callback is not a function data type throw error
    if (typeof fn !== 'function') throw Error();

    function g () {
        this.off(event, g);
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    this.on(event, g);
    return {
      unsubscribe: () => this.off(event, g);
    };
}

// which can later be called as

const subscription = e.once('test', test);
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

---

However, since you are already keeping track of the original function via `g.fn = fn;`, you could adjust your `.off` method to check whether any registered event handler has such a property that matches the passed in value. Something like:

```
// if it is registered then unregister it!
this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName].filter(
  handler => handler !== callBack && handler.fn !== callBack;
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**edit**: whoops, misunderstood the question

in `off`, you're looking for `test` in `this.events[eventName]`, but in `once`, you're pushing a proxy/wrapping function `g`.

***old answer***

in

```
function g () {
  this.off(event, g);
  fn.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

`this` refers to `g`, not `Emitter`, you have to either bind

```
function g() {}.bind(this)
```

create a closure with `this` i.e.

```
let self = this

function g() {
  self.off // Emitter#off
}
```

or use an ES6 arrow function

```
const g = () => {
  this // Emitter
}
```

Comment: *"`this` refers to `g`, not Emitter"* It does not. The value of `this` depends on how `g` is called. Also, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the OP's question.